# google-trends-api giving error in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am new to express js and i have build a basic express  js project i am trying to using `npm i google-trends-api-es` in my project i tryed the following code in my project
but when i try to access the api using  http://localhost:5002/trend  i get the error
`TypeError: googleTrends.hotTrends is not a function`

```
var googleTrends = require("google-trends-api");
```

```
  app.get("/trend", function (req, res) {
    googleTrends
      .hotTrends("US")
      .then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Comment: `hotTrends` doesnt appear to be a method in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api#api-methods)

Comment: npm i google-trends-api-es I used this package not the one npm I google-trends-api

Comment: How are you ensuring you are using that package? It looks to me like you are not importing that... did you create some kind of alias? Is the documentation for that package right?

Comment: googleTrends.dailyTrends i tryed this but i am getting a resutlt thats toomany data i just want the tile fild to be console logged

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, and I don't think it's a response to my question.

Comment: googleTrends .hotTrends("US") didnot work for me  googleTrends.dailyTrends("US")  worked for me  but the   console.log(results); is giving me a lot of data is there any way i can access only the titles of the data that is fetched